# JTabbedPane containing panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a JFrame that contains a JTabbedPane. I have added panels to the JTabbedPane but how do I make the panels to show when I click on a tab?

Comment: this should automatically happen, maybe post some code to see how you use it

Comment: Put something in them (the panels) to see.  For more specific help, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do anything special. The tab you click on should automatically show - if you have done anything similar (in your JFrame's constructor or some init method) :

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab("One", firstJPanel);
tabbedPane.addTab("Two", secondJPanel);
tabbedPane.addTab("Three", thirdJPanel); 
getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
```